# Problem in installing the neuralpy in python

Tags: python, neural-network

While installing neuralpy in python I am getting below erro

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\charl\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\charl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fa01we2c\\neuralpy_8ec49cf461be46ffb3bf043793885892\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\charl\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fa01we2c\\neuralpy_8ec49cf461be46ffb3bf043793885892\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\charl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-yo3cz8nu'
         cwd: C:\Users\charl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fa01we2c\neuralpy_8ec49cf461be46ffb3bf043793885892\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\charl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fa01we2c\neuralpy_8ec49cf461be46ffb3bf043793885892\setup.py", line 2
        print find_packages(exclude=['DEPneuralpy'])
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You are trying to install a Python 2 only package on Python 3.

Comment: so how should i install neuralpy in python 3

Comment: You might have missed the "only" in my earlier comment.

Comment: Ohh sorry, Now I got it. Thanks, I have installed the neural-python it solved the problem. Thank You very much.